# Left join resulting in weird output in QGIS's Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, sql, spatial-join, query, virtual-layer

I want to join two layers, a polygon layer `"plan"` and a point layer `"education point"`. My goal is to join the data from `"education point"` layer to the `"plan"` layer if the point is inside a polygon.

Since some polygons don't intersect with any point, and I still want to keep those polygons visible, I used `left join`. But the result only shows polygons intersecting with a point.

Here's my query:

```sql
SELECT pl.geometry,ed.*
FROM "plan" AS pl
LEFT JOIN "education point" AS 'ed' ON st_intersects(pl.geometry,ed.geometry)
WHERE pl."function" in ('primary school', 'middle school')
AND ed."studyArea"='yes'
```

Comment: Your WHERE does not permit NULL ed values.

Comment: Do you mean that the `and` will return false, thus giving no result, if any one of two layer is NULL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the last part of the where clause: `and ed."studyArea"='yes'`

Vince beat me to it.

As soon as you include WHERE criteria like that on the table on the right side of the join it sort of implicitly becomes an inner join.  Think about it: if there is no `education point` to intersect with the `plan` object then the value of ed."studyArea" wont be 'yes', it will be NULL, which doesn't match your criteria.
You can either change the last part so the query reads:

```
select pl.geometry,ed.*
from "plan" as pl
left JOIN "education point"as'ed' on st_intersects(pl.geometry,ed.geometry)
where pl."function" in ('primary school','middle school') and 
(ed."studyArea"='yes' or ed."studyArea" IS NULL)
```

Or you can move the filtering condition on the right table to the JOIN clause:

```
select pl.geometry,ed.*
from "plan" as pl
left JOIN "education point"as'ed' on st_intersects(pl.geometry,ed.geometry)
    AND ed."studyArea"='yes'
where pl."function" in ('primary school','middle school')
```

I like the second approach myself, it seems to better express your intent, which is to join the `plan` table to the subset of records in the `education point` table which have `studyArea='yes'`

Comment: The second query is quite different. If there is a `studyArea='no'`, the original query will return no record at all while the 2nd of your answer will still return the `pl` record